# Can't find excel file when using Panda (pd.read_csv())

Tags: python, file, csv, pandas

Simple problem, when trying to access a cvs in the same directory as the .py file running it:

```
training_set = pd.read_csv("boston_train.csv", skipinitialspace=True, skiprows=1, names=COLUMNS)
```

The result is:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'boston_train.csv' does not exist

Comment: Has something moved your current working dir?
to make sure that you grab the file alongside this, you could do a os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "boston_train.csv")

Comment: You can confirm that you are in the expected working directory by using `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the absolute path to the file so it can be found since it may not exist in the same place that your python file exists.

Comment: Ah yes that worked... haha I actually tried that earlier but thought it didn't work cause it failed on the next (unedited) import file "boston_test.csv". I'll mark as correct when it's been 5 min.